# In Swift/SpriteKit Can you use a ShapeNode as mask in a CropNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode, skcropnode, skeffectnode

I've been trying to combine randomised `SKShapeNode` shapes with textures using a `SKCropNode` but it doesn't seem to work. I assume that `SKCropNodes` only work with bitmap graphics such as PNG.

```
       //define sprite as crop node
       let cropSprite = SKCropNode()
       //create spriteNode with texture and add it
       let texSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rock")
       cropSprite.addChild(texSprite)
       //set mask of cropping Sprite to (predefined) shape node with .maskNode
       cropSprite.maskNode = myShapeNode
       //add final cropped sprite to scene
       self.addChild(cropSprite)
```

In this case nothing appears. If I don't set the:

```
cropNode.maskNode = myShapeNode
```

the cropSprite appears as a normal sprite with a texture added.

Any Ideas?

Many Thanks,
Kw

Comment: How have you setup `myShapeNode`? Is it an image?

Comment: It looks to me like you have it setup right. The only thing I can think of is that you did something wrong setting up `myShapeNode`. Can you show us how you setup `myShapeNode`, or a picture of what the mask looks like?

Comment: Afaik as I know this is not possible. No matter what shape you are using, mask will have the size of a shape's *frame*. That is how it was earlier... What you can do, is to create a texture from a shape and set it as a mask. That always worked.

Comment: myShapeNode is a SKShapePath set up with points defined and the path closed. How do I convert the shape to a texture? Thanks fro all your comments.